# Make Hadoop run as a Kerberos user

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, kerberos

There is a user in Kerberos named "foo", the hadoop cluster is Kerberos secured. I want the hadoop cluster to run the job as "foo", how can I do that? What is the configuration that allows a hadoop client to specify a kerberos user account name to run with, just like hadoop cluster 'kinit username' then run the mapreduce job? Just FYI, hadoop 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for user impersonation.  This can be accomplished in the core-site.xml file.  See the following example:

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.super.hosts</name>
     <value>host1,host2</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.super.groups</name>
     <value>group1,group2</value>
</property>
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for someting similar to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656543/how-to-get-kerberos-instead-of-delegation-token-in-hadoop-mapreduce. But I don't want to pass the tgt over the network.

Comment: Huh - but the TGT is **designed** to be passed over the network. It has no other purpose: you first get a TGT from the Kerberos service, then you send it to 1..N services, then these services send it back to Kerberos for validation (e.g. for obtention of a service ticket).

Comment: You seem right. But my concern is, if tgt is being passed around by Kerberos, then I don't need to take care of the security thing. But if I somehow implement it myself (like mentioned in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656543/how-to-get-kerberos-instead-of-delegation-token-in-hadoop-mapreduce), then security might be an issue. So what I'm looking for is some mechanism provided by hadoop and Kerberos to do so